Aiogram bot can't respond in Channel Comments
I wrote a simple aiogram chat-bot code, which can write down messages to mongodb database:
@router.message(Command('memorize'), IsChat(['group', 'supergroup', 'chat', 'channel']), IsAdmin(admin_id))
async def memorize_handler(message: Message) -> None:
    reply = message.reply_to_message
    if not reply:
        await message.answer("⚙ Can't find user")
        return
    
    text = reply.text
    if reply.from_user.username:
        username = reply.from_user.username
    else:
        username = reply.from_user.full_name
    try:
        user_id = reply.from_user.id
        mention = reply.from_user.mention_html(reply.from_user.first_name)
        memory_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        memorize(memory_id=memory_id, text=text, username=username, user_id=user_id)
        await message.answer(f' Succesfully saved message from {mention}')
    except:
        await message.answer(f'❗ Couldnt save message from {mention}')

Filter code here:
class IsChat(BaseFilter):

    def __init__(self, chat_type: str | List[str]) -> None:
        self.chat_type = chat_type
    
    async def __call__(self, message: Message) -> bool:
        if isinstance(self.chat_type, str):
            return message.chat.type == self.chat_type
        return message.chat.type in self.chat_type

The problem is, when you call bot from channel-chat - he doesn't handle updates for some reason.
However, bot still works in private chats, groups and supergroups.
I already tried to expand IsChat filter with 'channel' and 'chat', but it didn't work out

next time use ``` to format block of code.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

@furas, yeah, ik that i have to use ```, but i was drowsy and it bugged out xD
I'll try and print debug. Already had it in mind, but anyways thank you!

I figured out what was the problem.
On each message I had filter IsAdmin, as well as IsChat.
Code for IsAdmin:
class IsAdmin(BaseFilter):

    def __init__(self, user_ids: int | List[int]) -> None:
        self.user_ids = user_ids
    
    async def __call__(self, message: Message) -> bool:
        if isinstance(self.user_ids, int):
            return message.from_user.id == self.user_ids
        return message.from_user.id in self.user_ids

Basically it compares passed admin ID and checks if it equals id from a message.
I forgot, that I have to add my ANONYMOUS USER ID (which is literally id for channel chat admin).
IsChat needs 'supergroup' in that case, because channel chats are supergroups instead of regular groups.
Hope I helped you.
